# Java game, calculate curve

Tags: java, game-physics

I am making a simple game that requires to do something similar as in the fruit-ninja game. I am now trying to make the objects fly from the bottom to the screen to the right in a curve, like this (but from a random position instead of the middle):

[image]

Because I have so little knowledge in mathematics I am stuck on this for quite some time now. How should I calculate this?

I got it to work in a very simplistic and nasty way, but the object had a static speed, instead of nice smoothing, and even I didn't know what I had just made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Newtons first law of motion, an object moves with a constant speed in a constant direction unless an external force acts on it. That means each object has a position (represented in X and Y coordinate) which is changed by a vector (represented by speed in x-direction and y-direction) each game-frame. When you get that running, you are already halfway there.

```
for (GameObject object: gameObjects) {
     object.position.x += object.vector.x;
     object.position.y += object.vector.y;
}
```

But in this case, you have a force which affects the objects: Gravity. Gravity is a constant acceleration into the Y-direction. That means the vector is changed every frame by the gravity:

```
for (GameObject object: gameObjects) {
     object.vector.y -= GRAVITY;
     object.position.x += object.vector.x;
     object.position.y += object.vector.y;
}
```

Comment: But lets say the starting y = -500, the vertical speed (vector y) = 5 and the gravity is 2 (arbitrary number, I have no idea). That would mean that it would subtract two and add 5 each game tick, this will show a steady speed of 3. Should the speed or the gravity fluctuate?

Comment: @Gideo You add the gravity to the speed, not the position. In the first frame you would add 5 to the position, in the second you add 3, in the third you add 1, in the fourth you would subtract 1, in the sixth you would subtract 3. The result is constant downward acceleration.

Comment: Right, it worked! Was way easier than expected. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use initial speed, the launch angle, and the acceleration due to gravity in the [kinematics equations.](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1dkin/u1l6a.cfm)

Comment: This is way too much for my simple assignment, thanks anyway. I'm going to try to implement this in my personal project!